# json array to bigroad table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help populating my table with JSON array based on last and previous result in Bigroad Scoreboard format.

```
[{"result":"M","no":"1"},{"result":"M","no":"2"},{"result":"M","no":"3"},{"result":"D","no":"4"},{"result":"M","no":"5"},{"result":"M","no":"6"},{"result":"M","no":"7"},{"result":"W","no":"8"},{"result":"W","no":"9"},{"result":"M","no":"10"},{"result":"D","no":"11"},{"result":"M","no":"12"},{"result":"W","no":"13"},{"result":"M","no":"14"}]
```

ive tried counless times to no avail i keep getting stuck at the comparison with last and previous objects of the json array.

im using this to populate another table i tried approaches similar to this

```
function history() {

$.getJSON('/history.php', function(data) {

    $.historyText = '';

    $.each(data, function(i) {

        $.winner = data[i].result;
        $.no = data[i].no;
        $.historyText = '<div class="history ' + $.winner + '" >' + $.no + '</div>';
        $(".cols-" + i).html($.historyText);

    });

});
```

}

I need it to output like this.
any suggestions would be greatly apreciated.

```css
table  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
table td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cols-0">1m</td>
    <td class="cols-5">8w</td>
    <td class="cols-10">10m</td>
    <td class="cols-15">13w</td>
    <td class="cols-20">14m</td>
    <td class="cols-25"></td>
    <td class="cols-30"></td>
    <td class="cols-35"></td>
    <td class="cols-40"></td>
    <td class="cols-45"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cols-1">2m</td>
    <td class="cols-6">9w</td>
    <td class="cols-11">11d</td>
    <td class="cols-16"></td>
    <td class="cols-21"></td>
    <td class="cols-26"></td>
    <td class="cols-31"></td>
    <td class="cols-36"></td>
    <td class="cols-41"></td>
    <td class="cols-46"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cols-2">3m</td>
    <td class="cols-7"></td>
    <td class="cols-12">12m</td>
    <td class="cols-17"></td>
    <td class="cols-22"></td>
    <td class="cols-27"></td>
    <td class="cols-32"></td>
    <td class="cols-37"></td>
    <td class="cols-42"></td>
    <td class="cols-47"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cols-3">4d</td>
    <td class="cols-8"></td>
    <td class="cols-13"></td>
    <td class="cols-18"></td>
    <td class="cols-23"></td>
    <td class="cols-28"></td>
    <td class="cols-33"></td>
    <td class="cols-38"></td>
    <td class="cols-43"></td>
    <td class="cols-48"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cols-4">5m</td>
    <td class="cols-9">6m</td>
    <td class="cols-14">7m</td>
    <td class="cols-19"></td>
    <td class="cols-24"></td>
    <td class="cols-29"></td>
    <td class="cols-34"></td>
    <td class="cols-39"></td>
    <td class="cols-44"></td>
    <td class="cols-49"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry but to me that table and it's order seems completely random. Exactly how are you planning to map it and where does the `m`,`w`, and `d` come from?

Comment: m,w and d comes from a database where in the values where placed based on the result. i was hoping for something like if prev(object) == last(object) do you have any suggestions?